# Perda de reputação repentina: "Votos a favor em série revertidos"

Tags: suporte, serial-voting

Ontem(*20/02/2014*), Achei estranho já ter alcançado os +200 de reputação máximos diários às 10 da manhã, notei que recebi alguns upvotes incomuns, porém fiquei feliz por isto, meio sem entender porém até aí tudo bem.

Continuei o dia usando o SO, ganhei mais alguns upvotes porém não me geravam reputação obviamente, pois eu já havia o limite diário.

Logo depois, à noite(porém acho que já estava contando como o dia seguinte), fui acessar o SO e me deparei com uma surpresa:

[image: votos em série revertidos]

> **-53** - 8 horas atrás - reversão - Votos a favor em série revertidos

Fiquei completamente sem entender, e realmente gostaria de saber o que aconteceu, simplesmente do nada me tiram 53 pontos de reputação e nem deixam uma explicação sobre isto.

Acredito que tenha sigo um bug/problema do Sistema, alguém já teve este problema antes?

Answer (score 17):

Esse é um script que previne **fraude de votos**. Ele funciona nas duas direções:

- Se alguém votou contra vários dos seus posts seguidos (por ressentimento devido a uma discussão, por exemplo), e esse script detecta isso, ele reverte todos os votos contra, te devolvendo a reputação perdida.
- Se alguém votou a favor de vários dos seus posts (por exemplo, num esquema de troca de votos), o script reverte todos esses votos a favor, te retirando a reputação ganha.

### Fiz algo errado?

Não. O problema da fraude votos está em quem **votou**, não quem **foi votado**. Além disso, é tudo uma heurística: o sistema determinou que o número de votos que tal usuário te deu não corresponde à probabilidade experimental desses votos terem sido genuínos, e concluiu que aquele usuário estava tentando explicitamente te favorecer.

### E quanto ao limite de reputação?

Ok, os votos "fraudados" não foram merecidos, e tinham que ser removidos mesmo, mas e quanto aos votos "verdadeiros" que outros usuários te deram e que não foram contabilizados por você ter atingido seu limite diário? Felizmente, o script que faz a reversão [leva isso em consideração](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/177950):

> Se você tinha atingido seu limite de reputação, o valor pode acabar ficando em branco caso nenhum dos votos sendo revertidos de fato afetou sua reputação naquele dia.

Ou seja, os primeiros votos em série foram retirados e "substituídos" por aqueles que você recebeu no restante do dia, e só quando eles acabaram é que o sistema começou a deduzir reputação de fato da sua conta. Ou seja, nenhum dos seus votos a favor genuínos foi perdido!

Comment: Nota: no seu caso particular, você recebeu `30` upvotes num período de `4` minutos (`04:23 - 04:27`)! Acho que está óbvio que aguma coisa só podia estar errada... Pouco antes também houve `6` upvotes num período de `2` minutos (`04:18 - 04:19`), esses de um usuário diferente - pois alguns desses votos se sobrepõem.

Comment: Tem certeza que contou com os votos que eu recebi quando estava com o limite estourado? E outra coisa, como eu sabia que o limite tava estourado, não estava "com a corda toda" se é que você me entende, achei esse sistema meio injusto. Não tenho culpa nenhuma se alguém do nada foi com a minha cara.

Comment: @PauloRoberto Certeza eu não tenho, só estou citando a resposta no "metão"... Sobre estar "com a corda toda", paciência, foi uma escolha sua (participar menos pelo potencial de recompensa menor) e deu no que deu. Mas agora que você já sabe como os votos em série funcionam, se isso acontecer de novo você pode simplesmente ignorar o limite e continuar respondendo - já sabendo que os votos injustos vão ser retirados mesmo no final do dia. P.S. você convidou algum amigo recentemente pra esse site? Um que não conhece a mecânica dele, e portanto não sabe que o "toma-lá-dá-cá" não é legal?

Comment: (pergunto isso porque as pessoas estão acostumadas - em redes sociais por exemplo - a "curtir" posts de amigos por ser amigos, sem saber que aqui se espera um comportamento mais imparcial. Um erro honesto, diria, não estou acusando ninguém de malícia)

Comment: Já mostrei o site para outras pessoas, porém nenhuma se manifestou dizendo que criou a conta ou coisa do tipo. Que eu saiba. Mas aparentemente não existe motivo para que alguém tenha feito isso, estou intrigado com isso realmente gostaria de saber o usuário mas acho que é impossivel né

Comment: @PauloRoberto pense se alguém tivesse te dados uns 20 votos negativos do nada, você também não teria culpa de alguém _não_ ter ido com a sua cara, você não ia querer que fossem revertidos? Do mesmo jeito que é injusto perder um monte de pontos por esse motivo é injusto ganhar pontos assim. Sobre descobrir quem é, não acho provável que você consiga, talvez os moderadores tenham esse poder, mas duvido você conseguir tirar essa informação de algum deles. Além do mais essa informação não é relevante para nós usuários.

Comment: Mas não é neste ponto que eu estava. Eu tenho a mesma opinião que você acabou de citar, **é claro que eles devem ser revertidos** porém no final do dia é tarde demais pra você ter sido meio que "enganado" pelo sistema de reputação, e também por ter tido uma falsa esperança de estar ajudando, e também porque sua rep foi bloqueada pelo motivo de ter chegado no limite máximo diário.

Comment: @PauloRoberto sobre a falsa esperança de ter ajudado te garanto que não vai acontecer de novo, da próxima vez que vc ver mil votos a favor do nada sua sensação vai ser `ó não, de novo não`. Sobre o limite ter sido atingido e votos legitimos nao terem sido computados com certeza é injusto, mas não sei se é esse o caso, vi rapidamente que vc obteve muito mais do que 6 votos a favor em série e só foram revertidos 53 pontos, é provável (não fiz as contas, mas aconselho vc fazer) que vc tenha tido 147 pontos legítimos e uns 200 não legítimos (perdi a conta de quantos votos a favor em série vc teve)

Comment: @PauloRoberto Se você quer saber com certeza se os votos após o limite foram computados ou não, é só fazer uma contagem manual... Seja pela IU mesmo, seja por meio [de uma "auditoria" de votos](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43004/177950): visite [esse link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/reputation) e veja como sua reputação foi calculada de fato (cada um só pode ver o seu, então não tenho como te ajudar nisso).

Answer (score 6):

Isso acontece quando um mesmo usuário dá muitos votos a seu favor em um curto período de tempo.

[Esta resposta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/235103) fornece alguns detalhes sobre o ocorrido. Transcrevo a parte que fala sobre "Votos a favor em série":

> ### When does serial upvoting occur?
>
> Most often when you get unexpectedly serial upvoted, believe it or not, it's just a user trying to give you extra reputation. They saw a post of yours that was extraordinarily helpful to them and they feel that going through your posts systematically and upvoting them is the appropriate way of granting you additional reputation (apparently they've forgotten about the bounty system).
>
> Occasionally, it also occurs between two users who have made an agreement to upvote each other, or between one user and a sock puppet account trying to game the system for extra reputation (which will often lead to suspension).

Em uma tradução "livre":

> ### Quando ocorre o a série de votos a favor?
>
> A maior parte das vezes que você recebe uma série de votos a favor, acredite ou não, é somente um usuário tentando te dar uma reputação extra. Ele vê um post seu que é extraordinariamente útil para ele e, então, sente que uma forma apropriada de lhe agradecer é sistematicamente percorrer todos os seus posts votando a favor, para lhe dar uma reputação extra.
>
> Ocasionalmente, também acontece de dois usuários fazerem um acordo de votar a favor um do outro - ou entre um usuário e uma outra conta "fantoche", tentando enganar o sistema por alguns pontos de reputação extra (o que pode levar a suspensão).